# Show 10 records with highest balance

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

I have table with records `'username'` and `'balance'`. How to show 10 usernames with highest balance?

Extra: How to show but only when they have more than 1.000.000$?

My Table:

[image]

Comment: These are very fundamental SQL questions. You should start by reading a book about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are *very* basic SQL statements.  You probably should find a good SQL tutorial and spend some time playing with the various `SELECT` clauses.  In your case:

- Just order your results in descending `balance` and limit to 10 records?

  ```
  SELECT username FROM mytable ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 10
  ```
- Add a `WHERE` condition to filter for only those records with a balance over your specified threshold:

  ```
  SELECT username FROM mytable WHERE balance >= 1000000
  ```

Comment: It should be: "`SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY 'balance' DESC LIMIT 10`". What about extra to show but only when they have more than 1.000.000$?

Comment: PS: and btw this is not what I've asked for. It just shows first 10 records, not the richest usernames.

Comment: @IlikeITalot: If you quote your identifiers in that way, MySQL will evaluate them as string literals which won't give the outcome you want.  And yes, it will show 10 records, but they will be the 10 richest usernames as desired.

Comment: `SELECT username FROM table ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 10` - now it works great! Thanks!

Comment: OK can you help with that: `Why

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
      echo $row['username'] . " " . $row['balance'];
      echo "<br />";
      }

Outputs: 

> **Notice**: Undefined index: balance in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\richest.php on line 12
rekin76 

When I call:

    $query="SELECT username FROM iConomy ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 10";
On table: http://i.stack.imgur.com/6tQk2.png`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to **sort** the balance first and limit the result by 10:

```
SELECT   `username`, `balance` 
  FROM   `table_name` 
ORDER BY `balance` DESC 
 LIMIT    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
     select username, balance from table_name where balance >= 1000000 order by balance DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''iConomy' ORDER BY 'balance' DESC LIMIT 10' at line 1

Comment: @LolCoder if you want to escape table name and column names, don't use single quote but instead use backtick ( **`** )

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT username FROM mytable WHERE balance>1000000 ORDER BY balance DESC LIMIT 10
```